# Alamofire CAN'T make User-Agent at default setting

Tags: ios, swift, httprequest, alamofire

```
    AF.request("http://myURL.com/hey",
               method: .get,
               parameters: nil,
               encoding: URLEncoding.default,
               headers: nil,
               interceptor: nil).response { res in
                debugPrint(res)
    }
```

I install Alamofire 5.2 version for HTTPRequests etc..
It's just send a simple GET Request.

I Got 500 error from server, cause there is no User-Agent header.
When I checked Server's request log, there is no User-Agent header.

It's just a simple get request, why Alamofire does not send `User-Agent` header?

Answer (score 0):

It's odd that a server returns a 500 unless there's a `User-Agent`. Alamofire always attaches a `User-Agent` (as a convenience, it's not required), so my guess is that your server can't parse the Alamofire `User-Agent` for some reason. You should log your outgoing traffic to double check. If it somehow doesn't have a `User-Agent`, you can add one directly using Alamofire's `HTTPHeader.defaultUserAgent` value.